# How to get exact value from input using codeigniter $this->input->post('fieldname')?

Tags: php, codeigniter, post

I am entering text in an input as `<br/>`, but when i am getting this field value using $this->input->post('fieldname') it is returning `<br>` instead of `<br/>`. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: i am giving <br/> as input, and it is returning <br>. even i mentioned it in my question but this stackoverflow is considering it as break and not showing those charecters

Comment: Did you use html entities https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

Comment: No, i didn't use html entities. But when i am using $_POST['fieldname'] it is getting exact value <br/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable `global_xss_filtering`:

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;
```